# Reactjs+Flow: onChange throws error

Tags: reactjs

I have the following stateless component that I'm type checking using Flow:

```
//@flow

import React from "react";

export const Picker = (
  { options }: { options: Object },
  { onChange }: { onChange: (e: SyntheticEvent<any>) => Function }
) => {
  return (
    <span>
      <select onChange={e => onChange(e)}>
        <option defaultValue=" ">Pick Year</option>
        {options.map(year => (
          <option value={year} key={year}>
            {year}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </span>
  );
};
```

When I trigger the onChange event I get the following error:

```
Picker.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: _onChange is not a function
    at onChange (Picker.js:11)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:201)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:466)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:488)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:586)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:597)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:567)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:728)
    at runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:737)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:4201)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:12537)
    at batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js:1939)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4282
```

What am I doing wrong? FYI if I remove the type checking and just use vanilla reactjs the onChange works.

Comment: *"FYI if I remove the type checking and just use vanilla reactjs the onChange works."* I bet your are doing more than that. At the moment your function expects **two** arguments, whereas usually stateless React components expect a single argument (props). Your function should be defined as `({options, onChange}: {options: Object, onChange: ...}) => ...`. I bet in the process of removing the type annotation you are also changing the function definition to receive a single argument.

Comment: @FelixKling you are correct, changed the signature to:

export const Picker = ({
  options,
  onChange
}: {
  options: Object,
  onChange: (e: Event) => void
})

Answer (score 0):

Stateless React components accept *a single* argument, "props". But your function definition expects *two* arguments, `onChange` being a property of the value passed as second argument. Since React will never pass a second argument it will never be set.

`options` and `onChange` should both be properties of the first argument, which means that function should be defined as

```
export const Picker = (
  { options, onChange }: { options: Object, onChange: (e: SyntheticEvent<any>) => Function }
) => {
  ...
};
```